# Google Drive "Gnome Online Account" Mount

Tags: gnome, mount, nautilus

I was very pleased to see that there's now a method to integrate a google drive into Nautilus on 16.04 using this link:

http://www.linuxtechi.com/access-google-drive-in-ubuntu-16-04/

But now I am wondering if I can take it a step further and mount the google drive somewhere so I can use bash to do recursive copies, etc?

Thanks.